# CountIf cell value meets a condition

Tags: excel

Hi I have a row of calculated values that I need to count based on a condition.

I have the conditions working in conditional formatting so that is the condition is met the cell changes color, however I need to find the totals of each color.

`=AND($V1/$Z1>0.5, $V1/$Z1<=0.79)`

so for this I want to only count values if this statement is true

`=COUNTIF(Z:Z, (AND($V1/$Z1>0.5, $V1/$Z1<=0.79)))`

currently this `returns 0` when there is 10 values that meet this criteria

does anyone know if `countif` can be used like this?

Comment: Have you tried using the `countifs`-function? Its made for several criteria. [LINK](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)

Comment: there isn't 2 criteria, there is only one criteria

Comment: One criterion is that the number must be `>0.5`. Another criterion is that it must be `<=0.79`. Let's count the number of criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I can see your issue, I've had a play around and am unable to crack it, if you wish to keep it in a singular cell you'll probably need to go down the route of an array formula. Its probably complicating it too much and you should look to have a helper column,

in Column AA, have the formula `=$v1/$z1`, then for your count write:

`=countifs(AA:AA,">0.5",AA:AA,"<=0.79")`

Comment: I agree - why make it complicated? And it also simplifies error handling in the event that $z1 could be zero

Comment: definitely! I'd personally want to be able to glance over the results in the helper to see where its fallen over instead of investigating what part of the formula isn't working -

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without a helper column using the Sumproduct() function.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($V$1:$V$100/$Z$1:$Z$100>0.5),--($V$1:$V$100/$Z$1:$Z$100<=0.79))
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($V$1:$V$100/$Z$1:$Z$100>0.5)*($V$1:$V$100/$Z$1:$Z$100<=0.79))
```

This will count all instances where the values in V1 to V100 divided by the values in Z1 to Z100 are between 0.5 and 0.79

Note that SumProduct is essentially an array formula (even though it does not require confirmation with Ctrl-Shift-Enter, but it evaluates each range as an array), so you don't want to use it with whole column references. If you want to retain calculation speed, make sure to refer to used rows only, not gazillions of empty cells.

Comment: i tried this however i think it breaks because not every value in the z column has a value - some have n/a for other reasons.

Comment: Any formula that is applied on a range with errors will produce an error. Consider removing the errors before applying the formula.

Comment: thats unfortunatly not possible - i was hoping for some sort of solution using IFNA